# Get Java version from PowerShell of remote server

Tags: java, powershell, version, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am trying to write a script in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) that will use the invoke command with credentials on a remote machine to execute code that will return a string containing the Java version on that machine. Java is not installed, sometimes it is just dropped in the server as a [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) folder and the application is pointed to that location, so unfortunately I cannot use the registry to find the Java version. The only idea I came up with is to call from within the invoke command something along the lines of:

```
& "path_to_java.exe" "-version"
```

Or even something more complicated and then use a regular expression to find the version:

```
start-process $java -ArgumentList "-version" -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardError "$path\tempoutput.txt"
$javaversionoutput = gc "$path\tempoutput.txt"
del "$path\tempoutput.txt"
```

However, on some servers I keep running into an issue where it is complaining about not having enough heap space to run that Java version command (through the invoke command on that remote server).

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\java.exe
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Could not creat...irtual machine.:String) [],     RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : <server>
```

From my research it has to do with the MaxMemoryPerShellMB that is set for a remote PowerShell session. On some servers it is set to 150, on some it's 1024. So sometimes I can successfully get the `java -version` to run from the PowerShell remote session, and sometimes I cannot, because there is too little memory. If I set it on the remote machine by logging in and doing it manually:

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1000"}
```

It starts to work. But I cannot go to each server each time and set it manually. If I try to set MaxMemoryPerShellMB through an invoke command, it says I don't have access, even though I can use the same account to change MaxMemoryPerShellMB on the server if I login and do it directly.

I feel like I have run out of solutions and was hoping to find some help here. Sorry if there has been a topic for this, I only found three and none of them answer my question. Below are the references if you guys are interested. There really is nothing I could find :P

- *[Running Java remotely using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741676)*
- *[How to get the Java version in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890926)*
- *[Cannot run Java from the Windows PowerShell command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811332)*

Comment: Can you try adding this argument to the jvm: `-Xms 10m`.  That will, hopefully, to 10m.  I don't know if this will work, since the jvm may actually be trying allocate space for stuff, but it's worth a try.

Comment: are you on an elevated PowerShell prompt when you are running invoke-command?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using WMI?

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name like 'Java%'" | Select -Expand Version`

Comment: @Dallas Moore, yes, Java is not always installed, sometimes it just a jdk folder in some location, we just point the application (like jboss) to it from the start up batch script, so I cannot use Win32Product since Java is not always installed.

Comment: @CodeChimp I've tried playing around with the settings, but I get Invalid initial heap size

Comment: Just wanted to add to the conversation, @DallasMoore one reason why people shouldn't use Win32_Product is because it is slow, and the query can time out causing you to not get anything back (for more details see: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/04/19/how-to-not-use-win32_product-in-group-policy-filtering/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I would just check the version of the file `java.exe`, something like

```
$Machines = Get-Content C:\Lists\Servers.txt

$Machines | for-each{

$java = gci '\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe'

$java.VersionInfo
```

And you get a `VersionInfo` *object* back , something like

```
 ProductVersion   FileVersion      FileName
 --------------   -----------      --------
 7.0.510.13       7.0.510.13       \\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

Or probably `$null` if path not found (of course you can check for that first with test-path but whatever). Good thing is that you can do *real operations* with the VersionInfo object if you so choosed, one of the awesome benefits of powershell. And Java sucks.

Comment: Hard-coding the assumption of JRE and version 7 into a script to determine the java version...?

Comment: @EricKramer fair enough, though in my defense I worked in a managed environment at the time, and I was the one managing the machines' configuration so that caused a bit of a blind spot in my answer. If I updated this, the spirit of the answer would remain the same~ using the `gci` command in powershell on an exe. I would update it to search both `Prog Files` and `Prog Files (x86)`, filter the results for `java.exe` and run `gci` on all of those, and print out a pretty table.

Comment: fair enough. I do prefer your use of the metadata compared to other responses that make assumptions about `java -version` output. Thanks for your reply and your updated suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one liner for getting the latest java version installed. If u have older versions installed too it only returns the latest:

```
[system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo]::GetVersionInfo(('C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\'+([regex]::matches((&"java.exe" -version 2>&1)[0].ToString(), '(?<=\").+?(?=\")').value.Insert(0,"jre")) + "\bin\java.exe"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with no problem

```
gc "D:\serverlists\serverlist.txt" | foreach {  
[system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo]::GetVersionInfo("\\$_\c$\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"); }
```